# delphi 7 TImage and TImageList

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, timage, timagelist

let i be integer private

the code

```
procedure TForm1.Image1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inc(i);
  ImageList1.GetIcon(i mod 4,Image1.Picture.Icon);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  i:=0;
  ImageList1.GetIcon(i mod 4,Image1.Picture.Icon);
end;
```

how do i stretch the icon from the list to fit the size of Image1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.Image1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  icon: TIcon;
begin
  inc(i);
  Image1.Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);      
  icon := TIcon.Create;
  try
    ImageList1.GetIcon(i mod 4, icon);
    DrawIconEx(Image1.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, icon.Handle, Image1.Width, Image1.Height, 0, 0, DI_NORMAL);
  finally
    icon.Free;
  end
end;
```

## Better Approach

Sometimes it is a bit awkward to use Delphi since the extent of cooperation between the VCL and the native Windows API is somewhat unclear. If the above code doesn't work (I get the feeling it is leaking icons), here is a pure native approach (`uses ImgList, CommCtrl`):

```
procedure TForm1.Image1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  icon: HICON;
begin
  inc(i);
  Image1.Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
  icon := ImageList_GetIcon(ImageList1.Handle, i mod 4, ILD_NORMAL);
  try
    DrawIconEx(Image1.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, icon, Image1.Width, Image1.Height, 0, 0, DI_NORMAL);
  finally
    DestroyIcon(icon);
  end
end;
```

Comment: if you change the code and remove the icon := TIcon.create and the line icon.free; this code works as charm and ill mark it as the answer.

Comment: @none: Removing these lines will make the code not work... At least in Delphi 2009. Maybe `GetIcon` works in a different way in Delphi 7.

Comment: Anyhow, let's skip the VCL and do things natively! See my updated code.